# Logout button not function

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic4

So i use logout button function on my tabs page to navigate back to login page. Unfortunately i cant click 'signout' button when user already login and register

Ive tried auth function to navigate back to login

tabs.page.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from '../user.service';
import {AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Router} from '@angular/router'
import {AngularFirestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore'

@Component({
selector: 'app-tabs',
templateUrl: 'tabs.page.html',
styleUrls: ['tabs.page.scss'],
})
export class  TabsPage implements OnInit {
constructor(
public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
public router: Router,
public afstore: AngularFirestore
 ) {}

ngOnInit()  {
}
 async logout() {
 try { 
 this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
this.router.navigate(['/loginPage']);
} catch (error) {
 console.log('Error', error);
}
}
}
```

tabs.page.html

```
 <ion-item>
 <ion-button ion-button color="danger"   (click)="logout()" full>signOut
</ion-button>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `await` in there as well as `async`.

```
async logout() {
  try { 
    // add await here:
    await this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    this.router.navigate(['/loginPage']);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error', error);
  }
}
```

Or alternatively you can do it with the `.then()` style of writing:

```
return this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
  this.router.navigate(['/loginPage']);
}).error((error) => {
  console.log('Error', error);
});
```

Otherwise the router will redirect to the next page before the `signOut()` can finish running.